# Will mobs fight each other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to pit mobs against each other? I was hoping to create a boxing ring-like area where I could spawn mobs to fight each other.

Edit: Can I get two zombies to fight each other?

Edit2: Can Ghasts fight each other because they use range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mob Arena - Mob vs. Mob](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241937/mob-arena-mob-vs-mob)

Comment: (Flagging an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because the newer question says this is possible, whereas the older one says it is impossible)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, but in vanilla Minecraft one of them must be a skeleton. (Or perhaps a ghast or blaze; though I've never personally seen them aggro another mob, I don't think the code specifically prevents it.) You have to get the other mob between the skeleton and something that will aggro the skeleton (such as yourself, or a snow golem) so that when it tries to shoot it hits the other mob instead. This will aggro the other mob, and then they'll fight.

It's fairly limited, but it is possible.

(Note that if a creeper is killed by a skeleton it will drop a music disc instead of gunpowder. These pit fights are fun *and* profitable!)

No, you can't make two zombies fight. Because of the way melee damage is coded, melee attacks can never cause "friendly fire": melee monsters acquire their target first, then deal direct damage to that target and only that target when they're in melee range. They don't attack like the player, where they swing and then damage is applied to whatever entity they connect with. Consequently, a zombie will never accidentally hit and damage another zombie. And since being damaged by another monster is the only way for a monster to aggro against another monster, zombies (and melee monsters in general) will never target each other.

No, ghasts won't fight each other. They appear to be programmed to ignore each other. I tested this by creating an arena with one "caged" ghast and one floating freely, switching to survival mode, and getting the caged one to shoot at me. Unlike skeletons, which will turn on each other when they suffer friendly fire, the ghast happily ignored the fireballs to its back and kept attacking me.

Comment: Hmm, wonder what a fight between a skeleton and zombie pigmen would be like :D

Comment: You say one has to be a skeleton, presumably because of the ranged attack. Have you tried using a ghast instead?

Comment: @dlras2 I haven't! Worth a try.

Comment: Can zombie pigmen attack each other?

Comment: @YoungGuilo ... Do you have any reason to believe that what I wrote about melee mobs doesn't apply to zombie pigmen?

Comment: No I was just wondering.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Right. Why were you wondering if the answer already says "no" to all melee monsters, which includes zombie pigmen? Is the answer unclear on that point?

Comment: Snow Golems aggro against all hostile mobs except creepers.  Etho [designed a device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SaFdmTeb_o) to cause creepers to aggro on skellies (although they won't aggro back) using snow golems.

Comment: @MBraedley Yeah, but snow golems aren't hostile monsters. You can make most anything fight a snow golem. And creepers will already aggro on skeletons if shot by them and they lose their aggro on the player at the same time.

Comment: The point was more that the player need not be involved in order to get a creeper to aggro on a skeleton.

Comment: @MBraedley Oh, because skeletons will target snow golems too. I see what you're getting at. I can work that into the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer but for future visits YES. Today I dodged 2 skellys, one arrow hit the other skelly and they turned on each other. So if they do friendly fire each other then yes.

Comment: This doesn't say anything not addressed in the current answer though.

Comment: If this had been given as an answer when the other was given I would have upvoted. So I did. Thanks.