# How to make mobs attack each other in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a relatively easy way to make mobs attack other mobs, for example zombies attack other zombies? I have tested summonning a snowball as another mob over a zombie, so the zombie thinks it was the other zombie that hurt him, but it didn't work at all, or I did something wrong.
I'm playing in 1.16 (20w22a).
I tested this command:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:zombie,limit=1,sort=nearest] as @e[type=minecraft:zombie,limit=1,sort=furthest] run summon minecraft:snowball ~ ~3 ~
```

I also tested these commands, but they didn't work :(

```
1 /summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {UUIDMost:1L,UUIDLeast:0L}
2 /summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["target"]}
3 /execute as @e[tag=target] at @s run summon snowball ~ ~4 ~ {owner:{L:0L,M:1L}}
```

here is an video link!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mob Arena - Mob vs. Mob](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241937/mob-arena-mob-vs-mob)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 That is not a commands question and the answers do not contain commands. @ pppery The answers there are outdated and partially never even worked (especially the `HandItems` part, you need a `Count`). @ zombie1111 The snowball method is pretty much the best idea already that I would have. If that doesn't work, then I doubt that anything will.

Comment: I just tried your commands in the lower box and they work for me. Can you maybe make a screen recording of you executing those commands so that we can see what is going wrong? Also, that first command box can't work, the `as` reference doesn't matter for the snowball.

Comment: Fabian röling  why do you always vote down my questions?  all questions that you have comment on is disliked :(  why?

Comment: Random, I guess? I did not downvote this question. But anyway, I watched the video and it seems like we're both doing the exact same thing in the same version. Maybe try it in a new world? That would be the only idea I have left now.

Comment: i tested it in a brand new world and it still doesnt work

Comment: Then I'm **really** interested in the answer, because I have no idea anymore. We both executed the same commands in the same version under the same circumstances. I can only guess a super weird bug, which depends on the OS or Java version or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not universal to all mobs, you could name a vindicator "Johnny", and it would attack all mobs in its vicinity, except for other illagers.

Alternatively, you could try spawning a skeleton and a different mob, and going into Survival mode, running between the two mobs. The skeleton would try and shoot you, but you dodge it, causing the fired arrow to hit the other mob. This would cause a mob fight to be staged.

I hope these methods work well.

Comment: The asker wants one specific mob to attack one specific other mob, with just commands.

Comment: The "Johnny" vindicator actually will attack other Illagers, and the mobs won't fight back either

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /team and make two teams and assign the mobs to the teams. The mobs will fight each other automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you position a skeleton behind another mob and the skeleton shoots that mob, they will attack each other, or you can use a vindicator named "Johnny" which will attack every mob around it (including other Illagers), but those mobs won't fight back. Enemies accidentally attacking each other is the best way to do this, and it's super easy to set up too. Otherwise, TGPMinecraft has a good method for doing this and his answer is useful if you mean to do this by commands

Answer (score -2):

I know that archers can trigger attack between mobs, try with an arrow