# How to make hostile mobs hostile to other mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On our minecraft realm I am a necromancer. Using the /team command I control hostile mobs to attack other players.

I was hoping to make a way to make my wither skeletons and vex attack other mobs.

If anyone has any ideas to make this possible using command blocks please let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Mob Arena - Mob vs. Mob](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241937/mob-arena-mob-vs-mob)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a skeleton and another mob, then if you get yourself almost shot by the skeleton, dodge it to make it hit the mob behind you, and they will start fighting each other.

Comment: I don't think this directly would work very well but I think you're on to something, maybe you gotta somehow make them hit each other just once

Comment: I need to change the AI